# How to clear dotnet-ef error file not found <project>EntityFrameworkCore.targets

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have refactored an ASP.NET Core Entity Framework code-first app to Blazor server-side using Entity Framework 6.0.0. All my CRUD operations work as intended but when I finally wanted to update the schema and perform a code-first migration to SQL Server, I ran into this strange problem.

Apparently in the `obj` folder of my project there is suppose to be a generated file

```
...\<solution folder>\<project folder>\obj\<project>.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets
```

This file is missing and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to re-generate.

**Questions**

1. What tool is responsible for generating the `<project folder>\obj\<project>.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets` file?
2. How do I force the file to regenerate?

Error examples:

```
dotnet-ef --version
```

> Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 6.0.0

```
dotnet-ef migrations list
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
> Could not find file '/obj/.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'.

```
dotnet-ef migrations add init0
```

> Could not find file '/obj/.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'

Entity Framework Nuget packages used in project:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore Version="6.0.0"
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore Version="6.0.0"
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI Version="6.0.0"
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version="6.0.0"
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version="6.0.0"
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version="6.0.0"
- Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore Version="6.0.0"
- Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core Version="6.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be Windows Defender Ransomware Protection selectively blocking dotnet.exe file and folder actions.  To solve the issue I had to

1. Enable Controlled Folder Access
2. Allow an app through Controlled folder access
3. Add an allowed app: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"